# Some Glyphicons not displaying

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, icons, glyphicons

I have bootstrap installed and currently trying to place some icons on my website.

Strange thing is that for example `envelope` icon is displaying:

```
<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-envelope"></span>
```

while `search` or `shopping-basket` are not:

```
<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span>
<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-shopping-cart"></span>
```

I have `glyphincons-halfings-regular` fonts installed and available.

What could be the reason?

I use bootstrap 3.3.7

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.

Comment: It's quite obvious that if I'm complaining that they don't show - I want them to show. And that's what they supposed to do glyphicons - to display. There is no error otherwise I would have mentioned it.